# EF error: The instance of entity type 'Object' cannot be tracked because another instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I'm running into a loss with this one and new to Blazor and trying to learn it (.NET 5)

I have a simple model:

```
public class Status
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

In `Startup.cs`, I register my db and services.

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")),(ServiceLifetime.Scoped));

 services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
 services.AddScoped<IStatusRepo, StatusRepo>();
 services.AddScoped<IStatusService, StatusService>();
```

The code behind file of my component is below. The `GetStatus` call returns a different dto than the update status service method accepts so I convert it in the `UpdateStatus` method.

```
public partial class EditStatus : ComponentBase
{
        [Parameter]
        public int StatusId { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        IStatusService StatusService { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        NavigationManager navigationManager { get; set; }

        public bool ShowLoadError { get; set; } = false;
        private StatusDetailDto StatusToEdit { get; set; } = new StatusDetailDto();

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await GetStatusToEdit(StatusId);
        }

        public async Task GetStatusToEdit(int statusId)
        {
            try
            {
                StatusToEdit = await StatusService.GetStatusById(statusId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowLoadError = true;
            }
        }

        protected async void UpdateStatus()
        {
            UpdateStatusDto updatedStatus = new UpdateStatusDto();
            updatedStatus.Id = StatusToEdit.Id;
            updatedStatus.Name = StatusToEdit.Name;

            StatusDetailDto statusUpdated = await StatusService.UpdateStatus(updatedStatus);

            if (statusUpdated != null)
            {
                navigationManager.NavigateTo("status/manage");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No here");
            }
        }
    }
```

The service layer is:

```
public async Task<StatusDetailDto> UpdateStatus(UpdateStatusDto statusDto)
{
    Status statusToUpdate = mapper.Map<UpdateStatusDto, Status>(statusDto);
    Status updatedStatus = await statusRepo.UpdateStatus(statusToUpdate);
    return mapper.Map<Status, StatusDetailDto>(updatedStatus);
}
```

And the repo

```
public async Task<Status> UpdateStatus(Status Status)
{
   if (Status is null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Nulls are not allowed.");

   try
   {
        Status.LastUpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;

        // THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR!
        _dbContext.Entry(Status).State = EntityState.Modified; 

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Status;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Perhaps my service lifetimes are wrong? I've tried transient lifetime for my `dbcontext` too. What could throw this error?

> The instance of entity type 'Status' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.

Answer (score 0):

At first fix startup file by removing ServiceLifetime.Scoped from AddDBContext

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
```

Then change code of your UpdateStatus

```
public async Task<Status> UpdateStatus(Status status)
{
   if (status is null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Nulls are not allowed.");
   try
   {
    var existedItem=_dbContext.Set<Status>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(i=i.Id==status.id);
       if(existedItem==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Item is not found.");
      existedItem.LastUpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
      _dbContext.Entry(existedItem).State = EntityState.Modified; 
      await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
      return Status;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would I need to get the item again when I already have it in the args?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. It still throws the exception and skips over the saveChanges call.

Comment: But your comment got me to fix it in a similar way, so thanks!

Comment: It could be something else. I modified your code slightly and it worked fine. I wasn't trying to be rude, appreciate your response.